# How to fix 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./routes"' in React?

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, asp.net-core-2.0

I am a beginner in asp.net core and React.js, I have a problem in developing a web app using Visual Studio 2017, web API using asp.net core and front end using React. I try to use Grid from Devexpress to build a grid view then come out an error which is same as [TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873599/typeerror-webpack-require-i-is-not-a-function)

After I add in the same code as shown in the solution provided in the link above another error come out:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./routes"

How can I solve this error?

Comment: can you please share the location of route.js and file where you are using it.

Comment: write import from './Something'

Comment: the routes file is tsx file, it locate at './ClientApp'

Comment: are you using redux, as i know `routes` are inside `/ClientApp/src/app/routes.tsx`

Comment: I'm not using redux, my routes file is inside ./ClientApp/routes.tsx, without 'src' and 'app' folder