# Unhandled Runtime Error: TypeError: __webpack_require__.t is not a function, in **live server** but not in **localhost**

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am developing a e-commerce site. everything works fine in localhost. but after deployment in live server this error pops up. After reloading the page again the error goes away.

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  getProducts as fetchProducts,
  selectProductList,
} from "../store/reducers/Products";
import { Rings } from "react-loader-spinner";
import { AppDispatch } from "../store/store";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import ProductListTable from "../components/product/ProductList";
import { selectUserInfo } from "../store/reducers/Auth";
import Router from "next/router";

const ProductList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const products = useSelector(selectProductList);
  const userInfo = useSelector(selectUserInfo);
  const hasAccess =
    userInfo?.permissions.find((item) => item.name === "product.update") ||
    userInfo?.permissions.find((item) => item.name === "product.delete") ||
    userInfo?.permissions.find((item) => item.name === "product.read");


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      if (!hasAccess) {
        Router.push("/");
      }
    }
  }, [userInfo]);

  return (
    <Layout>
      {userInfo && products && products.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="p-5">
          <ProductListTable products={products} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="flex h-full w-full justify-center mt-[20%]">
          <Rings color="#377D71" height={200} width={200} />
        </div>
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

1. this is the main page. here I am loading the **ProductListTable**
   component
2. I am fetching products in `useEffet`

I am using(package.json):

```
  {
  "name": "project name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.36.3",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "evergreen-ui": "^6.10.1",
    "flowbite": "^1.4.7",
    "flowbite-react": "0.0.27",
    "heroicons": "^1.0.6",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.1.5",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates there is a problem with one of the imports.

you should also try using [useRouter hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) of NextJs instead of directly importing Router object in client app. [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325145/import-router-from-next-router-is-it-ok)

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873599/typeerror-webpack-require-i-is-not-a-function) and please share detailed error message incase this information does not help.